# How to copy a document in Firebase Firestore in same collection?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How do I copy a Document in same Collection of Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no copy operation.  You will have to read the document, then write the document back with a new document ID.